# Military Time Difference in Java

Tags: java

Here's my TimeInterval class:

```
public class TimeInterval {

   private int fTime;
   private int sTime;

   public TimeInterval(int fTime, int sTime) {
      if(fTime < 0 || fTime > 2400 || sTime < 0 || sTime > 2400) {
          System.out.println("Illegal times, must be < 2400 and > 0)");
          System.exit(0);
      } else {
          this.fTime = fTime;
          this.sTime = sTime;
      }
   }

   public int getHours() {
      return Math.abs((fTime - sTime) / 100);
   }

   public int getMinutes() {
       return Math.abs((fTime - sTime) % 100);
   }

   public double getDecimalTime() {
      return getHours() + ((double) getMinutes() / 60);
   }
}
```

and my tester class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestTimeInterval {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the first time: ");
      int fTime = s.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter the second time: ");
      int sTime = s.nextInt();

      TimeInterval t = new TimeInterval(fTime, sTime);

      System.out.printf("%s: %2d hours %2d minutes \n", "Elapsed time in hrs/min ", t.getHours(), t.getMinutes());
      System.out.printf("%s: %.2f", "Elapsed time in decimal", t.getDecimalTime());

   }    
}
```

However, it calculates certain time correctly, but if I enter for example 0150 and 0240, the difference should be 50 minutes, but instead it displays 90, and I need to make it not go over 60, and transform the remainder to hours and minutes. While if I enter some other numbers, it works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One solution: 1) take inputs as string 2) separate hour and minute and covert them to int, 3) calculate total minutes  4) convert the minutes again to hours and minutes and return

Comment: in your example: `240 => 2*60 + 40 = 160`, `150 => 1*60 + 50 =110.` Then `160-110 = 50` which is the correct answer

Comment: @jrook Is there any way I could do this with integers?

Comment: Yes. Basically you have a number between 0 and  2400 and want to extract its digits. The first two digits will be minutes and the last two (if any) will be hours. `num % 100` will be the minutes and `num / 100` will be the hours.

Comment: Also, note that your check won't work for a number such as `1385`. You need to first extract hours and minutes and check each separately

Comment: And just a hint: while testing your code, don't use a scanner. Simply write code that uses hard coded values. There is no need that a human keeps typing in the same data over and over again. Rather write many small test methods that use a specific data point and then write code that checks for the corresponding expected results. In other words: learn about unit testing may be even tdd.

Comment: Tip about terms: It is only "Military Time" in the United States. To the rest of the world it is simply known as *24-hour clock*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock

Comment: Note that at least one of 000 or 2400 must be a valid time, so saying 2400 > time > 0 means you can never specify midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered my own question, the solution was that I seperated the hours from the minutes part (*e.g. 1159 to 11 and 59*), multiplied the hours to get the minutes and added that to the rest of the minutes.

```
this.fTimeInMin = ((fTime / 100) * 60) + (fTime % 100);
this.sTimeInMin = ((sTime / 100) * 60) + (sTime % 100);
```

And then, in the `getHours()` and the `getMinutes()` method *transformed the minutes to hours and minutes*:

```
public int getHours() {
    return Math.abs((this.fTimeInMin - this.sTimeInMin) / 60);
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return Math.abs((this.fTimeInMin - this.sTimeInMin) % 60);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

```
Duration
.between(
    LocalTime.parse( "0150" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HHmm" ) ) ,
    LocalTime.parse( "0240" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HHmm" ) ) 
)
.toString()
```

> PT50M

## Details

Perhaps you are just working on homework. If so, make that clear in your Question.

But you should know that Java provides classes for this purpose.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. These classes work in 24-hour clock by default.

### `LocalTime`

For a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone, use `LocalTime`.

```
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 1 , 50 );
    LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 2 , 40 );
```

### `Duration`

Calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
    Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Generate text representing that `Duration` value. By default, [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is used.

```
    System.out.println( d );
```

> PT50M

### Parts

You can extract the parts if desired.

```
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
```

### Parsing

To parse your HHMM format provided by your users, use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HHmm" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "0150" , f ) ;
```

### Zones

Be aware that working only with time-of-day without the context of date and time zone can lead to incorrect results. If working in UTC, no problem. But if your time-of-day values are actually intended to represent the wall-clock time of a particular region, then anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) will be ignored by use of `LocalTime` only. In your example, there may be no two o'clock hour, or two o'clock have have been repeated, if occurring on a DST cut-over date in the United States.

If you implicitly intended a time zone, make that explicit by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
…
Duration d = Duration.between( zdt , laterZdt ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but I need to do it in the way previously mentioned, without using additional APIs. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So to figure out elapsed time between two 24 hour times you need to transfer to total minutes now the modulo functions you are using will not work as 1 hour = 60 min not 100 min.

So first to transfer all hours/minuets to minute time.

```
int ftminuets = 0;
int stminuets = 0;
int totalmin = 0;
int elapsed = = 0
while(fTime >= 100)
{
     ftminuets += 60;
     fTime -= 100;
}
ftminuets += fTime; //gets remaining minuets from fTime.

while(sTime >= 100)
{
    stminuets += 60;
    sTime -= 100;
}
stminuets += sTime;  //gets remaining minuets from sTime.

//time to subtract
totalmin = stminuets - ftminuets;
//now total min has the total minuets in what can be considered to be 60 min increments.  Now just to switch it back into a 24 hours time.

while(totalmin >= 60)
{
    elapsed += 100;
    totalmin -= 60;
}
elapsed += totalmin; //get rest of the minuets.
```

elapsed should now have the elapsed time in 24 hours time.

Comment: You need to first check if one time is greater that the other before subtraction or you can get a negative answer from the above.

Comment: Ohh and also check for improper time format @jrook said in his comment

Comment: I admit not the most elegant solution but I also wanted anyone coming to see this to be able to easily read the code and understand what its doing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is the solution you are looking. Splitting the mil.time so you can get the hours and minutes separately, then the rest is just somputations. Only thing you would accept the two params as Strings.

```
public class TimeInterval {
    private String fTime;
    private String sTime;
    private static int timeDiffMinutes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fTime = "0330";
        String sTime = "1330";
        TimeInterval t = new TimeInterval(fTime, sTime);

        System.out.println("timeDiff  " + getTimeDiffMinutes());

        System.out.println(t.getHours() + "...." + t.getMinutes());
        System.out.println(t.getDecimalTime());

    }

    public TimeInterval(String fTime, String sTime) {
        int fTimeInt = Integer.valueOf(fTime);
        int sTimeInt = Integer.valueOf(sTime);

        if (fTimeInt < 0 || fTimeInt > 2400 || sTimeInt < 0 || sTimeInt > 2400) {
            System.out.println("Illegal times, must be < 2400 and > 0)");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            this.fTime = fTime;
            this.sTime = sTime;
            getTimeDiff();
        }
    }

    public static int getTimeDiffMinutes() {
        return timeDiffMinutes;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return Math.abs(timeDiffMinutes / 60);
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return Math.abs(timeDiffMinutes);
    }

    public double getDecimalTime() {
        return getHours() + ((double) getMinutes() / 60);
    }

    public void getTimeDiff() {
        final int mid1 = fTime.length() / 2; //get the middle of the String
        String[] parts = {fTime.substring(0, mid1), fTime.substring(mid1)};
        String fPart = parts[0];

        final int mid = sTime.length() / 2; //get the middle of the String
        String[] sParts = {sTime.substring(0, mid), sTime.substring(mid)};
        String sPart = sParts[0];

        int toBeExcluded = (Integer.valueOf(sPart) - Integer.valueOf(fPart)) * 40;
        this.timeDiffMinutes = (Integer.valueOf(sTime) - Integer.valueOf(fTime)) - toBeExcluded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you check for wrong invalid entry? is that not necessary? if do, your method eventhough currently only need about less thann 30 operations will grow to much2 more operations, that is not to include the 0000 hours or 2400 hours issues.